# Unity Game doesn't fit android screen

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I was just testing my android app tonight when I found out that the app doesn't match the phone size.
I made the app specifically for my Android Phone ( SAMSUNG S8 ), with a resolution of 1440 x 2960, and yet when loading the app on the phone, it looks way bigger.
Any fixes to this?

Comment: Many ways... Check this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the Ui Scale Mode as Scale With Screen Size.

also, install the phone Devices simulator package to see the phone preview on Unity, It does not have to export your project just to see the preview

check this out
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.device-simulator@2.2/manual/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the screen ratio. When I had this issue it was due to a ratio issue.
In the `Player Settings` (Ctrl+Shift+B), set the screen width and Height you needs.

In the Supported `Aspect Ratio section`, I chose `Others`.

From the upper-left corner of the game preview window.